# Multiple columns on x-axis in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a dataset that looks like this

[image: See Image]

All of A1 - A15 have positive integer values

I want a graph with A1 - A15 on the x-axis and their values on the Y-axis with CN and RN as filters.

I am trying to create a bar chart. What should I be putting in Axis, Value, Tooltips, etc. This is my first time with anything like PowerBI.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with table that looks like this:

[image: Table1]

You can select columns `A1` through `A3` and, in the query editor, use Transform > Unpivot Columns to get a table that looks like this:

[image: Table2]

Once you have it in that form, you can put the `Attribute` (column names) on the Axis and the `Value` column in the Value section.

Once you add the `CN` and `RN` slicers it should look like this:

[image: Example Output]

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your reply! I tried implementing the steps you said and while I am able to apply other changes like splitting columns, deleting them etc., I am unable to unpivot them as, as soon as I click on the button, it tells me access to the resource is forbidden! I am using a Sharepoint list. I suppose I have access as I am still able to view all the data and perform other functions as mentioned. Can you help me with the same? Thanks again!

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different question.