# Use a row as X-Axis in Power Bi

Tags: data-binding, powerbi, dax

Target Visual:

[image: Target Visual]

Sample Data:

[image: Sample Data]

I'm trying to recreate the graph "Target Visual". The top row of my data gives my values in 15-minute intervals.

How can I display my data like the target visual?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [unpivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49823122/) your interval columns to reshape your data so that it looks like this:

| Date | UnitOfMeasure | Interval | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2019 | KWH_DEL | 0:00 | 27.12 |
| 01/01/2019 | KWH_DEL | 0:15 | 26.76 |
| 01/01/2019 | KWH_DEL | 0:30 | 26.76 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Then you can use `Interval` as your x-axis.